How can I replace one single pixel in a picture with a defined color?
I want to replace a single pixel in an image with a defined color, with the option, to set lines.
Example:
pixel 0,0 should be replaced with srgb(85,85,85).
Next step: pixel 0 to xxx should be replaced likewise.
I do not want to replace areas or colors, just lines. I am using the commandline.
As mentioned. One pixel after the other.

What did you tried or research?

Your question title and your question body do not seem to be in agreement. Do you want to write a pixel or a line?

It is most easily done with any image editor.

Please, if anyone knows an answer: How do i replace one single pixel with a color using the command line of Imagemagick

I do not understand why someone wants to score a question negative. A question is a question, nobody is forced to answer it. Just read and leave, if it doesn't make sense to you.

Use -draw like this to draw a blue point at coordinates (0,0):
magick -size 24x16 xc:red -fill blue -draw "point 0,0" result.png



Use the following to draw a line with colour srgb(85,85,85) from (0,0) to (32,0):
magick -size 64x64 xc:red -fill "srgb(85,85,85)" -draw "line 0,0 32,0" result.png



If you want to specify the new colour with hex, say red, use:
magick ... -fill "#ff0000" ...


If you already have an existing image, use:
magick ExistingImage.png -fill ... -draw ... result.png


If you already have an existing image, and you want to overwrite it, use:
magick mogrify -fill ... -draw ... ExistingImage.png


If you want to draw thousands of points on an existing image, create a script called points.mgk like this:
ExistingImage.png
-fill red -draw "point 0,0"
-fill blue -draw "point 0,1"
-fill lime -draw "point 0,2"
...
...
-write result.png

And run it with:
magick -script points.mgk


Thank you Mark,  magick ExistingImage.png -fill ... -draw ... result.png is, what I wanted..

Cool - glad it helped. By the way, surround your code with backticks to make it show up as code.

Mark: Thanks again for the scripting hint. I like to know about the basics rather than to use editors. Photoshop etc are great, but I am oldfashioned... :-)

Besides using -draw, you can also just insert the new pixel using Imagemagick (as an alternate method). Create a new pixel and composite it over the image at the desired location.
Unix Syntax:
magick background.suffix \( -size 1x1 canvas:"srgb(85,85,85)" \) -geometry +0+0 -compose over -composite result.suffix

Windows Syntax:
magick background.suffix ( -size 1x1 canvas:"srgb(85,85,85)" ) -geometry +0+0 -compose over -composite result.suffix


Note that canvas: is synonymous with xc:

Thanks. This is a good way to save some time. For the finer steps, I would use Mark's solution additionally.

Cool. Note that the parentheses are not really necessary here and the default size is 1x1 anyway, so both could be safely omitted.

Note also, that you can effectively draw a line, like you asked, using Fred's method magick -size 64x64 xc:yellow -size 10x1 xc:red -geometry +5+0 -compose over -composite result.png which draws a 10px wide line at coordinates (5,0).
